# rpy2 causes bad_alloc in vagrant machine

Tags: python, r, vagrant, rpy2, bad-alloc

I have a small django app running inside a vagrant virtual machine. The app provides an API that is supposed to make predictions using a random forest model. The model is provided to me as an .rds file, so I have to use R to work with it.

I set up rpy2 to execute a simple R script using the model:

```
# R Script
make_prediction <- function() {
    model <- readRDS("PATH/TO/MODEL.rds")
    dfInput <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
    library (ranger) # R library for random forest
    prediction <- predict(model, dfInput)
    return (prediction)
}
```

The corresponding python code looks something like this:

```
# Python code
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
def predict(r_file_path):
    with open(r_file_path, 'r') as f:
        r_string = '\n'.join(f.read().splitlines())
    self.model = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(r_string, 'model')
    return self.model.make_prediction()
}
```

When I call the API I get a 502 Bad Gateway Error, which I have traced down to bad_alloc in the uswgi logs:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Fri May  5 10:13:05 2017 - DAMN ! worker 4 (pid: 2484) died, killed by signal 6 :( trying respawn ...
Fri May  5 10:13:05 2017 - Respawned uWSGI worker 4 (new pid: 2495)
Fri May  5 10:13:05 2017 - mapping worker 4 to CPUs: 1
```

If I `vagrant ssh` into the virtual machine and run the R script form the command line it executes without a problem.

Also if I change the R script by outcommenting the line `prediction <- predict(modelProd, dfInput)` (and just return a constant value) it works from within the django API.

So it seems to boil down to a problem with rpy2 and the model I was provided. Am I using it wrong or is this a legitimate bug / memory leak in rpy2?

Comment: Which rpy2 version is this happening with ?

Comment: This is suggesting a bug with rpy2... or in the C extension of the R package(s) you are using. Does the computation of `prediction` complete without error (even if returning a constant value) ? Any chance you could dump a core and see in further details how this is happening ?